# How can I uniquely identify a chromecast chrome sender?

Tags: google-cast

When casting a tab from chrome, the receiver registers a new sender with an id like this:

```
18:client-69832
```

However, when the chrome tab is reloaded, a call to `castReceiverManager.getSenders()` now contains two entries and continues to increase every time the page is reloaded

```
castReceiverManager.getSenders() -> 18:client-69832
RELOAD
castReceiverManager.getSenders() -> 18:client-69832, 18:client-78542
RELOAD
castReceiverManager.getSenders() -> 18:client-69832, 18:client-78542, 18:client-84557
etc...
```

The first part `18:client` seems to remain consistent across reloads. Can we rely on this to uniquely identify the device? If not, how can we uniquely identify the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say unique, what is the scope that you have in mind If you are looking for something that persists between sessions, then that number s not unique. If you want something unique across sessions, one approach is to have each sender create such uid and communicate that to the receiver (if receiver needs to know).

Comment: The scope I have in mind is to uniquely identify the laptop / desktop computer to which chrome is running, similar to a MAC address. If this sort of UID is not available from the Chromecast Chrome SDK, then your suggestion to create one seems like the only option. Thank you @AliNadaaf.